# converting pandas string data to numeric for decision tree

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I am trying to convert several columns of string data into numeric to feed into a classification model. An example dataset with one modification column would be:

**input:**

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['nick', '12']]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
data
```

**output:**

```
    Name    Age
0   tom     10
1   nick    15
2   juli    14
3   nick    12
```

I realize that scikit learn doesn't handle string data very well, but for now I'd really prefer to press onward with it, if possible (company restrictions). However, my issue is that if I use

```
sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder
```

i am able to use '.classes_' to get some numeric values, such as:

**input:**

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(data['Name'])
le.classes_
vals = le.transform(le.classes_)
vals
```

I get

**output:**

```
array([0, 1, 2])
```

Since this array only contains three values, I cannot use

data['Name'] = vals

for assignment because my column length is 4 and my vals length is 3.

Considering this, is there an alternate way for me to go about this in scikit-learn or is my only option to use a different library?

Comment: vals = le.transform(data['Name'])

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this:

```
pd.get_dummies(data=data, columns=['Name'])
```

Output:

```
  Age  Name_juli  Name_nick  Name_tom
0  10          0          0         1
1  15          0          1         0
2  14          1          0         0
3  12          0          1         0
```

Now your data is ready for model training. Usually OneHot encoding is better than LabelEncoding because LabelEncoding implies there's a numerical relationship between your names. If Juli==0, Nick==1 and Tom==2, you're implying `July < Nick < Tom` which might cause troubles in some models.

Comment: I agree with one-hot encoding for this task, but it might also be worth mentioning the native sklearn [OneHotEncoder()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), it can be easier to use in the sklearn ecosystem

Comment: Ah, thank you. I did recently learn that you don't want an implied order but I got a little turned around and based on my reading, I thought get_dummies was NOT OneHot and LabelEncoding was. thank you for that correction.

So, does this process change if I need to do this for multiple columns in my dataset? I'm guessing no, as this is simply using a Boolean value? This is just adding a few extra features to my dataset. am I understanding correctly?

Comment: For me `pandas` is more straightforward, but if you're building `Pipelines` it might be better to use `OneHotEncoder`. If you want to add more columns add them to the `columns=['Name']` list, it's that easy and you get automatically an updated dataframe

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data['Name']= le.fit_transform(data['Name'])
```

This will assign labels to the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(data['Name'])
le.classes_
vals = le.transform(data['Name'])
vals
```

When you use `fit(data['Name'])`, you actually can use `fit(data['Name'].unique())`, because only unique values use for fit, but for `transform` you must use all your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer =Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy='mean', axis=0)

imputer=imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])

X[:,1:3]= imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])

#Concept of Dummy Variable, Handling the conflict of them

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
#We have to give the column number necessary to change it in numeric form
X[:,0]=labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
```

---

```
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features =[0])

X=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# prepare input features
def LABEL_Encoding(X):
    objList = data.select_dtypes(include = "object").columns
    print (objList)
    le = LabelEncoder()
    for feat in objList:
        data[feat] = le.fit_transform(data[feat].astype(str))
      
    return data
```